# Difference between `.NET Compiler Platform SDK` & `C# and Visual Basic Roslyn compilers`

Tags: .net, roslyn

In my Visual Studio 2017--15.8.5 on Individual Components tab I have two compilers or at least two checkbox. To be honest even if I have to much time working with VS I don't know the difference of this two compiler. I google it but I haven't find an clear explanation of what is the first or the second and what is the difference of these two.

[image: Image from VS installer]

I want to extend my knowledge in .Net and it could be a great help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilers are guys that just try to compile your code to `IL` in the `.NET`. During compilation compilers build a couple of different representations for the input code: AST, semantic model and so on, to apply a different analyzings under the code.

Instead of, **.NET Compiler Platform SDK** provide access, API, to the models which were built by compiler, that allow users to build a custom analyzers, code fixes and many other improvements. By the way, sdk has a couple of additional API, for example API to work with a project's system, that isn't a model was built by compiler, but was build by build system (**MsBuild**), and contains a helpful things help users to write them custom analyzers: **SyntaxVisualizer**, templates and so on. For more detailed info on SDK you cand find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/)